# Finding matched elements between rows (list of words) of a Pandas series & a given list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have a pandas series where each row is a list of words. 
[Example Series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWXRu.png)

I have a list of words, say *my_list* = ['ball', 'apple']. I want replace all the rows of the series with words that appear both in that row and in *my_list*. What is the fastest way to do this? Can vectorization be used for this type of task?

I want the result to be the following:[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWNw3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[['apple','ball','cat'],['cat','donkey'],['elephant','apple','rhino']]}, index=[0,1,2])

my_list = ['ball', 'apple']

pd.Series([[r for r in i if r in my_list] for i in df['col1']])
```

Output:

```
0    [apple, ball]
1               []
2          [apple]
dtype: object
```